# Trouble using angular/material

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, angular

I am attempting to refactor my code to use Angular/Material for the front end, however I cannot seem to get it to work...

I have followed what has been said on the [angular material website](https://material.angular.io) and from Youtube video tutorials, but it just doesn't seem to want to work.

I have run the normal npm commands:

```
npm install --save @angular/material@latest @angular/cdk@latest @angular/animations@latest
```

I have imported a material button into my `app.module.ts`, along with the animations:

```
// Other imports are above
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';

@NgModule({
  imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    Routing,
    GreyhoundComponentModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    MatCheckboxModule,
    MatButtonModule,
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  providers:[
    DecoratorUtils,
    Configuration,
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: AppHttpInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I have imported a theme into the CSS file: `style.css`

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

And in the HTML file I have used the element tags as given by the angular/material website:

```
<button mat-button color="primary">Primary</button>
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors in your console? Maybe you can prepare a JS Fiddle? https://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It's more proprietary code so I don't feel comfortable sharing the whole thing :-(... At the moment I am getting the output: Angular is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.. However, if I try to use a checkbox using the things the website has given as example I get: 'mat-checkbox' is not a known element:

Comment: @physicsboy try `import { MdButtonModule } from '@angular/material'` instead of `import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button'`

Comment: Change `import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';` to `import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material`

Answer (score 0):

Change to

```
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material';
```

To as you need to import button module from angular material and add

```
@import '~bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap';
```